# How do I import existing source files into JDeveloper?

Tags: java, jdeveloper

I am trying to create a project in JDeveloper and import several existing source trees into the project.  I don't see any option within the interface for doing this.  Am I just missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

File->Import
or 
New -> Projects->Project from WAR or PRoject from existing source